# Add support for separator character on cookie name

Tags: go, cookies

I am working with an external API/web that has a cookie with an `@` on its name. Go-lang does not support this and ignores the `Set-Cookie`.

How can I implement this without modifying the Go source code directly?

As implemented on Go:

```
http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1 specifies that:
set-cookie-header = "Set-Cookie:" SP set-cookie-string
set-cookie-string = cookie-pair *( ";" SP cookie-av )
cookie-pair       = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
cookie-name       = token

Then in http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-2.2, token is
specified as:
token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
separators     = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@"
                     | "," | ";" | ":" | "\" | <">
                     | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "="
                     | "{" | "}" | SP  | HT
```

Comment: Do two things: 1. Open a bug report for the API (it is broken). 2. Work with the raw HTTP header (where you can do whatever you or the API designer likes).

Comment: @Volker it is not broken. It just follows the spec. I've also figured this out.

Comment: It is broken because it uses an @ in a cookie value. That is the definition of broken.

Comment: @Volker oh I thought you were talking about the golang api. Yes, the external api I'm working with is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are just headers with key value pairs, they're not complex. So copy the code you need out from here, and use it to parse the set-cookie header instead in your own way, instead of relying on the stdlib.

https://golang.org/src/net/http/cookie.go

You could probably adjust this function to allow @:

```
func isNotToken(r rune) bool {
    // Allow @, unlike the go stdlib
    // document reasons here
    if r == '@' {
        return false
    }

    return !httplex.IsTokenRune(r)
}
```

Alternatively, get hold of the header and just write some simpler parsing code in this particular instance, as all you need to read is something like this:

Set-Cookie: example@example="abc";Path=/

You could probably get away using strings.Split or a regexp if parsing a simple predictable cookie value.

Comment: Thanks. I went with a transport approach and it does the job

Comment: @majidarif What is a transport approach?

Comment: @CeriseLimón like how this was done: https://godoc.org/github.com/StalkR/misc/net/http/spacecookies